# What's this thing by my front door?

Tags: outdoor, exterior, door-frame

[image]
[image]
[image]

It's covered in paint and I realized I can pull it out a bit. Really have no idea as to its intended function. This is a house in Boston built in the 1800s.

It pulls out to about 1 and a quarter inches and no further.

Answer (score 7):

Mechanical doorbell/chime, at a guess.

Operation might rotate, might be push-pull, probably missing parts in the house by now.

Answer (score 6):

Mechanical door bell.

Clean it up and polish the brass,

It looks decorative even if it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers state it is an actuator for a mechanical doorbell. Could have a pully on the shaft inside the wall. (Alternatively the bell might have been surface mounted or inset into the wall just opposite this knob.)

If the bell was high on the wall inside, rotation would have advanced a chain or cord inside the wall that went up to another pully on another shaft. That shaft would have gone from inside the wall to the interior space where there would be a bell affixed to the wall.

Alternatively, there might have been a light rigid rod attached to a disc on the shaft which went up to another disc on a shaft. Turning the knob in your pic would turn the shaft higher up and ring the bell.

Google "mechanical doorbell mechanisms".

The access to the chain and pulleys or rigid rod for service or repair could have been from outside or inside via a removable panel. How about editing your question  by adding pics of the inside wall opposite this actuator and above the door.